# JOIN запрос из двух связанных таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Проясните пожалуйста, сам понять вообще не могу.
Имеется 2 таблицы, posts и user. 
posts имеет столбцы id text author, а user имеет id name.
Столбец author связан с таблицей user.
При выводе данных из posts в цикле мы получаем id пользователя, но как вывести name вместо id?

```
$res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM post ");
$rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
foreach ($rows as $row){
    ?>
    <span><? echo $row['text'] ?></span><br>
    <span><? echo $row['author_id'] ?></span>
    <?
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример запроса или кода

Comment: Надеюсь в author айдишник?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin да

Comment: @JVic отредактировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $result = mysqli_query($link,"
    SELECT user.name, post.text 
    FROM post 
    INNER JOIN user ON post.author = user.id
  ");

  $str = '';
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $str .= '<span>' . $row['text'] . '</span><br>';
    $str .= '<span>' . $row['name'] . '</span><br>';
  }
  echo $str;
```

Нельзя генерировать строку вывода и выводить одновременно, нужно всегда стараться разделить эти части.

Неверно было использовано эту функцию [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php),так как она возвращает только одну запись с результата запроса

Comment: Не особо понимаю смысл объявления переменной $str перед циклом. Еще вы забыли $ в последней строке поставить)

Comment: Потому что нужно разделять логику формирования вывода и сам вывод. Вывод должен быть один, в одном месте. А у вас все понемногу и все на кучу, очень плохой стиль. Можно глянуть на MVC в php, там будет еще более ясно зачем так разделять. Да, забыл, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.text, u.name FROM posts p JOIN user u ON p.author = u.id
```